# jupyter notebook geopandas doesnt read my data when i call them

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas

#Firt of all im using new environment to install geopandas with conda cuz i didnt install it in(base) of jupyter notebook. Now my packages working but i cant read my data
Here is my error:
import pandas as pd
import geopandas
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import fiona

```
ülke = geopandas.read_file("countries.geojson")

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CPLE_OpenFailedError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
fiona/_shim.pyx in fiona._shim.gdal_open_vector()

fiona/_err.pyx in fiona._err.exc_wrap_pointer()

CPLE_OpenFailedError: countries.geojson: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

DriverError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-88e26eb4192f> in <module>
----> 1 ülke = geopandas.read_file("countries.geojson")

~\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py in _read_file(filename, bbox, mask, rows, **kwargs)
    158 
    159     with fiona_env():
--> 160         with reader(path_or_bytes, **kwargs) as features:
    161 
    162             # In a future Fiona release the crs attribute of features will

~\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\fiona\env.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    406     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    407         if local._env:
--> 408             return f(*args, **kwargs)
    409         else:
    410             if isinstance(args[0], str):

~\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py in open(fp, mode, driver, schema, crs, encoding, layer, vfs, enabled_drivers, crs_wkt, **kwargs)
    254 
    255         if mode in ('a', 'r'):
--> 256             c = Collection(path, mode, driver=driver, encoding=encoding,
    257                            layer=layer, enabled_drivers=enabled_drivers, **kwargs)
    258         elif mode == 'w':

~\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py in __init__(self, path, mode, driver, schema, crs, encoding, layer, vsi, archive, enabled_drivers, crs_wkt, ignore_fields, ignore_geometry, **kwargs)
    160             if self.mode == 'r':
    161                 self.session = Session()
--> 162                 self.session.start(self, **kwargs)
    163             elif self.mode in ('a', 'w'):
    164                 self.session = WritingSession()

fiona/ogrext.pyx in fiona.ogrext.Session.start()

fiona/_shim.pyx in fiona._shim.gdal_open_vector()

DriverError: countries.geojson: No such file or directory
enter code here
```

Comment: Could you please link us to the geojson file if it is a publicly available one? Is it happening with shapeflies as well or just geojson files?

Answer (score 0):

From the error description:

**CPLE_OpenFailedError: countries.geojson: No such file or directory**

**DriverError: countries.geojson: No such file or directory**

It literally seems like your are trying to open the file from a working path, where the file doesn't exists.

Please ensure that the file you are trying to read is in the same working directory as your Jupyter Notebook, or add the right path in your local machine to that same file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your geojson is in the same directory that your `.ipynb` file is.

Or you can just put the geojson file location in the read statement, for example:

```
ülke = geopandas.read_file("C:\user\folder1\folder2\data\countries.geojson")
```